# Error with python package importing another package using __init__

Tags: python

i'm learning package imports in python and i have the below folder structure.

```
import_test/
├── main.py
└── pack_1/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── pack_2/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── p2class.py
```

i have the below codes in each file.

main.py

```
import pack_1
```

pack_1/**init**.py

```
print('pack_1 imported')

import pack_2

print('pack_2 also imported')
```

pack_2/**init**.py

```
print('importing pack_2')

import p2class
```

pack_2/p2class.py

```
import pack_1

print('hi')
```

now, when i run main.py. i'm getting the below error

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pack_2'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a package, you must use [Package Relative Imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)

So, you would need to change your files as follows:

**pack_1.__init__.py**

```
print('pack_1 imported')
from .pack_2 import *
print('pack_2 also imported')
```

**pack_1.pack_2.__init__.py**

```
print("importing pack_2")

from .p2class import *
```

Then running main.py will give you the output of:

```
pack_1 imported
importing pack_2
hi
pack_2 also imported
```

However, it isn't usually necessary to have each `__init__.py` import the subpackages. It's more commonly used to import components of sibling modules, or files contained directly in the parent folder.

If you comment out the import lines from the files above, and make a `main2.py` as follows:

```
import pack_1.pack_2.p2class
```

Then importing the submodule `p2class` will implicitly import and run `pack_1.__init__.py` and `pack_1.pack_2.__init__.py`, resulting in the output:

```
pack_1 imported
pack_2 also imported
importing pack_2
hi
```

Answer (score 1):

All the modules would need to be directly exposed main.py as the code will be imported directly into main, not actually ran from pack_1.

Move pack_2 into the same directory where you have your main.py.

Comment: Thanks. that worked. But is there any way to make my implementation work without moving the folder to the top directory?